# What's the best way to get data with relations?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5.1

I need some help to find out a best way to fetch data from following table structure.

**Table One:** organisations id name etc.

**Table Two:** locations id name etc.

**Table Three:** organisaiton_locations this table holds the relation as follows:

```
id | organisation_id | location_id
```

- **id**: auto-increment
- **organisation_id** foreign key reference to id on organisations table
- **location_id** foreign key reference to id on locations table

Whey I try this with hasManyThrough, I get the correct number of items but they are mapped to **id** instead of **location_id**.

```
class Organisation extends Model
{

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Location', 'App\Models\OrganisationLocation', 'organisation_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Can you please help me understand how can I fetch all locations related to an organisation in a collection so that can be used in a transformer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `hasManyThough` just use the normal one, with **through** you are trying to access third level relation, where in your case it's not.

Simply replace it with:

```php
class Organisation extends Model
{

     public function locations(){
         return $this->hasMany(Location::class,'organisaiton_locations', 'organisation_id', 'location_id')->withTimestamps();
     }

}
```

and please remember to import your Location class (first argument in `hasMany` function) or just use it as string, the way you did

if you don't have timestamps in your junction table then remove this from the end of the above code `->withTimestamps()`

Comment: Thanks @mohamed, I opted to use ManyToMany approach by renaming the table name as per Laravel requirement and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends suggested to use ManyToMany relation with this kind of table relation and its works perfect. In case you are stuck with something like this, use ManyToMany with correct table name in alphabetical order and it works as per the framework without any hacks.

Cheers!!